# Snowflake dynamic where clause in SQL UDF

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dynamic-sql

I have a SQL UDF in Snowflake where I call the function with a parameter (function_input) which go into where clause:

```
WHERE X IN (SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(function_input, ',')))
```

But I would like to have it dynamic so if function_input have the value '*' then it means all, but I have not found any solution to use a "wildcard" within IN() statement.

Are there any way where I can use some kind of CASE in the the where clause, so I have one where clause when my input = * and a "normal" IN() when my input is 'x,y,z'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that LIKE ANY can help me:

```
WHERE X LIKE ANY (SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(function_input, ',')))
```

Where I can input a list  'x,y,z'  or I can input '%' as wildcard.